# How do I use jQuery effects as a function property

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function addClassFadeIn(elm,effect){
    console.log(elm);
    elm.find('.dropDown').effect;
}

addClassFadeIn('.hasDropDown','fadeIn()');
```

I want to add the jQuery effect as a function property and use it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

When accessing the property of a jQuery object via a string you need to use bracket notation. Also note that in your code `elm` is a selector string, so you need to wrap it in a jQuery object in order to call methods on it. Try this:

```js
function addClassFadeIn(selector, methodName) {
  $(selector).find('.dropDown')[methodName]();
}

addClassFadeIn('.hasDropDown', 'fadeIn'); // note no () here
```

```css
.dropDown { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hasDropDown">
  <div class="dropDown">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

It's also worth noting that the example is largely redundant, but I presume this is just a learning exercise.